# In android how to know 'Wireless Network' flag is enabled or not

Tags: android, geolocation

I am working on user speed calculation application where I used 'Network provider' to get location. I just want to know that how I know that whether 'Wireless Network' flag to access user current location is enabled or not.

For clarification Flag path : Setting -> Location & Securtiy -> Use Wireless network.
(Setting path from LG device.)

And also can we able to toggle this flag through code.

If any one known about this then please let me know, thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This preference is present in Settings.secure. So you cannot write such a setting programmatically. This has to be specifically enabled by User. Check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html